# Saving image to sd card folder

Tags: android, android-intent

am trying to create a folder on sdcard and save all images there and not on internal memory.

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1111;
    private ImageView mImage;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        //1
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
      File image = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator +"mypics");
    Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
            //2
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            EditText etext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLocation);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), data.getExtras().get("data").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            etext.setText(data.getExtras().get("data").toString());
            //3
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            //4
            String state=Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), state, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator +"mypics");
            if(!file.exists())
                if(file.mkdirs())
                    Log.v("Mobitracker","success");

             if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Yes its read only", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             if ( Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable ())
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Yes its internal card", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             //Create New file and name it Image2.PNG
             File file1 = new File(file, "Image2.PNG");
            try {
                file1.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file1);
                //5
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.flush();
                fo.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please take snap again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

This is my code for it, I tried many things but stillnot possible it is saving in internalmemory DCIM folder why?

Am getting output as

Mounted
Yes its read only

Am not connected to system but still same problem I even tried restarting phone and all but still same.
Am using sony xperia tipo mobile 4.0.4 os.

Please help me its frustrating I tried all threads.

can you guys help me please

My permissions are

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And also I could see bitmap image in image view but
  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), data.getExtras().get("data").toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

is returning some android.graphics@422020 some thing

Comment: Have you specified the relevant permissions in your manifest file?

Comment: http://android-spirit.blogspot.in/2013/07/camera-intent-in-android.html

Comment: Yes I have specified permissions

Answer (score 0):

You should use outputstream to write the content. Refer [here](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-file-to-sd-card) for help.

Or do something like (see [here](http://android-er.blogspot.co.il/2010/07/save-file-to-sd-card.html) the complete thread):

```
Button.OnClickListener buttonSaveOnClickListener
 = new Button.OnClickListener(){

  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   OutputStream outStream = null;
   File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "er.PNG");
   try {
    outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();

    Toast.makeText(AndroidWebImage.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(AndroidWebImage.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(AndroidWebImage.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

  }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) Android Training post carefully to figure things out. As the post says,

```
 The Android Camera application saves a full-size photo if you give it a file to save into.
```

so if you did pass the `Uri` of a file,it will be stored in DCIM only and you should access the image using this `Uri`.

[Check out similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185950/save-capture-image-in-sd-card-android)

Comment: Can I use that Uri to store in db? I mean can I use the same uri some other time and retrieve the image?

Comment: Yes you can use the Uri to store in db also and retrive the image.

Comment: File image = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator +"mypics");
        Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); Can I do like this and store this fileUri in db? what will be the file name?

Comment: Its always better to store the image path in database which you can get by `image.getAbsolutePath();`

Comment: Am getting Null pointer exception can you jst give me some lines of code for using uri?